convert this "value": "0x5d2761e5d85772" to ETH value
How can I convert this value to ETH value? Is this hexadecimal?
"value": "0x5d2761e5d85772"
I am getting insufficient funds to transfer this value but not sure what this value represents in ETH.

You can use the cast from-wei command in Foundry, like:
cast from-wei 0x5d2761e5d85772

which would give you the output as:
0.026220474255562610

That means the required value in ether is 0.026220474255562610.
However, if you just want to get the value in wei, you can convert the hex value i.e., 0x5d2761e5d85772 to the decimal format using cast to-dec command, like:
cast to-dec 0x5d2761e5d85772

which would give you the output as:
26220474255562610

That means the required value in wei is 0.026220474255562610.
